# Liquibase oracle multiple schemas with different credentials

Tags: oracle, liquibase

How to redefine liquibase.properties files for different changesets if there are several users (schemas) in the oracle database with privileges only for their schema?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [release notes for SQLcl 21.4](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/21.4/sqcug/using-liquibase-sqlcl.html#GUID-673321E9-1C06-4B9A-A373-52C2CB5AB7B0) (current latest version), they state

> In this release, you can only capture objects from the schema you are connected to in SQLcl.

So if you are using SQLcl and need to generate changes from multiple schemas, you will need to connect to each schema and generate the changes individually.

Answer (score 0):

When I have such projects as the one you described - with multiple schemas, I prefer to create a special user (schema) with privileges to other schemas and use this user in liquibase.properties file.

Basically, the easiest way is to create a specific role with grants to other schemas.

Comment: That won't work if new objects require privileges set by the owner. So ultimately you have to connect as the object's owner and give the grants to other users.